# C programming: Reverse ordered list

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop

I'm trying to "scroll" through a list of names I got the scroll down part right but I can't figure out how to go backwards (scroll up). I The error lies in the i + j -1, but I just cant get the right output without a segmentation fault. This is because I'm trying to access a negative number I'm assuming.

```
int i,list,j = 1;
char answer [5];
 do {
     if (strcmp(answer, "+") == 0) {
         printf("Number of Contacts = %d\n", count);
         for(i=1;i<6;i++) {
             if ((i + j) - 1 == count) {
                 printf("end of list\n");
                 break;
             } else {
                 list = i + j;
                 if(strcmp(contactData[(i+j)-1].company_name," ") == 0) {
                     printf("%d.\t%s %s\n", list, contactData[(i+j)-1].first_name, contactData[(i+j)-1].last_name);
                 } else {
                     printf("%d.\t%s\n", list, contactData[(i+j)-1].company_name);
                 }
             }
          }
      }

     if (strcmp(answer, "-") == 0) {
         printf("Number of Contacts = %d\n", count);
         for(i=1;i<6;i++) {
             if ((i + j - 1) < 0) {
                 printf("end of list\n");
                 break;
             } else {
                 list = j - i;
                 if(strcmp(contactData[(j-i)-1].company_name," ") == 0) {
                     printf("%d.\t%s %s\n", list, contactData[(j-i)-1].first_name, contactData[(j-i)-1].last_name);
                 } else {
                     printf("%d.\t%s\n", list, contactData[(j-i)-1].company_name);
                 }
             }
          }
      }

      printf("Action(+,-,#,A,X):");
      scanf("%s", answer);
      getchar();
      j++;

  } while (1)
```

This is my output:

```
Number of Contacts = 14
1.      Chiraq
2.      Cobra
3.      Andre D'Souza
4.      Gucci
5.        Jordan
Action(+,-,#,A,X):+
Number of Contacts = 14
2.      Cobra
3.      Andre D'Souza
4.      Gucci
5.        Jordan
6.      Migos
Action(+,-,#,A,X):+
Number of Contacts = 14
3.      Andre D'Souza
4.      Gucci
5.        Jordan
6.      Migos
7.      North Face
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: Arrays start at `[0]`. You should try to start with `j=0` and `i=0`. If j is your scroll position, why do you `j++` at every input? You don't show the list in reverse order, so don't have to test `if ((i + j - 1) < 0)`.  I think you only need one loop to show the entries and `if(*answer=='-') j--` and `if(*answer=='+') j++` with some test for j.

Answer (score 0):

If your `contactData` array starts at `[0]` and ends at `[count-1]` this example could work for you.

```
int i,list,j = 0;
char answer [5];
do {
    printf("Number of Contacts = %d\n", count);
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        list = i+j;
        if (list >= count) {
            printf("end of list\n");
            break;
        }
        if(strcmp(contactData[list].company_name," ") == 0) {
            printf("%d.\t%s %s\n", list+1, contactData[(list].first_name, contactData[list].last_name);
        } else {
            printf("%d.\t%s\n", list+1, contactData[(list].company_name);
        }
    }

    printf("Action(+,-,#,A,X):");
    scanf("%s", answer);
    if(strcmp(answer, "+") == 0) {
      if((j+1)<count) j++;
    }
    else if(strcmp(answer, "-") == 0) {
      if(j>0) j--;
    }
} while (1);
```